# Convert from xbox joystick buttons to the standard mobile joystick

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working in a 3D game in unity with multiple levels. In this level I have a first person character climbing ladder. I have used this asset from the asset store (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/39505). The joystick is not working on android device. The joykeys are for xbox.

What is the right joykey for the standard joystick used for mobile not xbox?

Comment: This might help you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17455/what-key-was-pressed.html